# Enable / Disable dropdown values in javascript in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

If I select Value 1 from first dropdown, it should hide value 4 from second dropdown. Similarly, If I select Value 2 from first dropdown, it should hide value 5 from second dropdown. I tried this. But couldnt get the right answer. Mainly it should work in IE 8.
I need pure javascript code. No jquery.

HTML CODE:

```
<select id="first" onchange="changeval(this)">
    <option id="all1">value 1</option>
    <option id="all2">value 2</option>
    <option id="all3">value 3</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
    <option id="all4">value 4</option>
    <option id="all5">value 5</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function changeval(obj) {
    switch (obj.value) {
        case 'value 1':
            document.getElementById('all1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('all4').style.display = 'none';
            break;

        case 'value 2':
            document.getElementById('all3').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('all4').style.display = 'block';
            break;

        default:
            document.getElementById('all3').style.display = 'block';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For basic funcionality you should just correct the ids in different cases because they are wrong now. For full funcionality you must pay attention for few other things:

1. In modern browsers if the option tag doesn't have value attribute they take the html for value but in IE8 it will be empty string so you need to add value attribute on each option element.
2. For example - if  selected value 3 from first dropdown you should see both values from the second dropdown so you can select 'value 5' for example. Now if you change option from first dropdown which doesn't allow 'value 5' in dropdown values it will be hidden but will be displayed if the dopdown is collapsed.
3. If you set display to none for some option in modern browser this option wont show when you're expanding the dropdown but the IE doesn't care about this display value. Some workaround that I suggest is to set the disabled attribute so you can see the 'hidden' values but you can't choose them. Another approach could be to remove html dom elements and add them again when needed but this will be a bit harder implementation.
4. It is preberably to put thi script part in document load event so you can be sure that elements are loaded when you're trying to attach them events.

**HTML**

```
<select id="first" onchange="changeval(this)">
    <option id="all1" value="value 1">value 1</option>
    <option id="all2" value="value 2">value 2</option>
    <option id="all3" value="value 3">value 3</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
    <option id="all4" value="value 4">value 4</option>
    <option id="all5" value="value 5">value 5</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function changeval(obj) {
    var selectedIsHidden = false;

    var all4option = document.getElementById('all4');
    var all5option = document.getElementById('all5');

    switch (obj.value) {
        case 'value 1':
            selectedIsHidden = all4option.selected;
            all4option.style.display = 'none';
            all4option.disabled = true;
            all5option.style.display = 'block';
            all5option.disabled = false;
            break;

        case 'value 2':
            selectedIsHidden = all5option.selected;
            all4option.style.display = 'block';
            all4option.disabled = false;
            all5option.style.display = 'none';
            all5option.disabled = true;
            break;

        default:
            all4option.style.display = 'block';
            all4option.disabled = false;
            all5option.style.display = 'block';
            all5option.disabled = false;
            break;
    }

    // Select the first option with display different than none
    // when we must hide the currently selected option
    if(selectedIsHidden) {
        var secondDropDown = document.getElementById('second');
        for(var i = 0; i < secondDropDown.options.length; i++) {
            if(secondDropDown.options[i].style.display !== 'none') {
                secondDropDown.options[i].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Call the changeVal function manually to ensure that selected value
// on the second drop down will be valid even after load. 
changeval(document.getElementById('first'));
```

**Fiddle**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5S2Ty/)